# How to subtract Sys with Timestamp from field and get hours and minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is my current query

```
SELECT 
        TABLE1.OUT_NO,
        To_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as "Current_Time",
        To_char(TABLE2.time_stamp, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as "Recorded_Time"
FROM TABLE1 TABLE1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 TABLE2 ON TABLE1.OUT_NO = TABLE2.OUT_NO
WHERE TABLE1.OUT_NO > '12345'
```

I need to subtract `Current_time` - `Recorded_Time` and get result in Hours and Minutes.
how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply subtract one from the other

```
select sysdate - systimestamp from dual;
```

Ensure that they're still a DATE and a TIMESTAMP, do not convert them to characters first. This returns an INTERVAL datatype.

---

Apparently this is giving you an integer, which means your timestamp is being implicitly converted to a date (or is in fact already a date and not a timestamp).

If this is the case you have the number of days between the two dates; multiply by the number of minutes in a day in order to get this in minutes:

```
select ( sysdate - systimestamp ) * 60 * 24 from dual;
```

Comment: How can I convert it to hours and minutes or just to minutes if it makes it easy.

Comment: for one of the record, duration should be 28 hours and 55 minutes and query I wrote is showing `1.2045949074074074074074074074` I don't know what this is.

Comment: That's a little bit weird, a date - a timestamp should give an interval (I thought). Apparently it's giving you a number which is a date - a date. I've updated my answer though...

Comment: thanks a lot, too bad I can't use `select t1.out, round((sysdate - systimestamp) * 60 * 24), -1) as Duration from table1 t1 where Duration > 120`.

Comment: nevermind I was able to but I had minor mistake in query thanks.

Comment: No you can't @Mowgli, but you can do this: `select t1.out, round((sysdate - systimestamp) * 60 * 24), -1) as Duration from table1 t1 where round((sysdate - systimestamp) * 60 * 24), -1) > 120`

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I done. Thanks again for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

use datediff() built-in function

```
    SELECT 
    TABLE1.OUT_NO,
    To_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as "Current_Time",
    To_char(TABLE2.time_stamp, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as "Recorded_Time",
    datediff(mi,time_stamp,getdate()) as DiffInTime
    FROM TABLE1 TABLE1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 TABLE2 ON TABLE1.OUT_NO = TABLE2.OUT_NO
    WHERE TABLE1.OUT_NO > '12345'
```

will show results in minutes. Dance from there.

Comment: Hi I get `ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling` error. I don't if it is supported.

Comment: sorry. didn't pay attention. apparently @Ben answered it already. see below